# Assign sound 60 seconds length to UILocalNotification

Tags: ios

my local notification is working so nicely, there is sound name call Alarm.wav 22 seconds length that I am assigning to local notification like

```
notificaiton.soundName = @"Alarm.wav";
```

and my local notification ringing 22 seconds

now my question is , is there any limitation to assigning sound to UILocalNotification with particular length limit

because when I am assigning Alarm.wav 60 seconds length then it's not working

is there any solution ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: length should be 30 seconds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can take this sound file length maximum 30 sec..

more than 30 sec length file not taken by notification.

Sounds that last longer than 30 seconds are not supported...By apple doc..

just take a look at this [Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 13):

If you read the documentation of [`UILocalNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it states that the [`soundName`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW8) property will only play for a maximum of 30 seconds.

> Sounds that last longer than 30 seconds are not supported. If you specify a file with a sound that plays over 30 seconds, the default sound is played instead.

Comment: As in links given in reference no longer state 30-sec constraint. Does that means now notification can play sound longer than 30 sec?